# How is the term "radix-point" (math) used for base b?

Tags: meaning, word-meaning, mathematics

If in the following phrase it is b=10 then the untested term 'b-unital' becomes 'decimal'. How do I use the term 'radix-point' in conjunction with base b in this phrase?

"b=base. S:number of the different cycles of digits in the b-unital expansions of 1/p,...,(p-1)/p where p=n-th prime."

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_point

Comment: Do you mean S is the length of the repeating cycles in the expansion? The number of cycles would be infinite.

Comment: Now I saw your question. No, it is an adjustment of the definition of sequence A006556 to base b (see the link). I would use the phrase "the number of different periods formed by fractions 1/p,...". Eg the prime number 13 has two different periods with a length of 6 digits each. I read from a reliable source that the terminology used by oeis in these cases is incorrect. I was confused too, but I hesitate to use a different terminology because I want to give the definition of a similar oeis sequence and English is not my mother tongue.

https://oeis.org/A006556

Answer (score 1):

In my experience the word used for base n arithmetic is n-ary (pronounced enery). You would use "radix point" in the same way as "decimal point". For example "If there are finitely many non-zero digits following the radix point in the n-ary expansion of a real number x then x is rational."

Comment: In the following source, in the "Template for integers" section, in the "Numeral system" line of the table, the terms N-cimal and N-ary are proposed. I think the term N-cimal is more natural and understandable.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:WikiProject_Numbers

An equivalent formulation of the same phrase that bypasses this problem is also acceptable.

Thank you